# How to reformat dates in an index using Pandas/in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My variable `dates_city` stores this:

```
Index(['2020-11-17T00:00:00', '2020-11-18T00:00:00', '2020-11-19T00:00:00',
       '2020-11-20T00:00:00', '2020-11-21T00:00:00', '2020-11-22T00:00:00',
       '2020-11-23T00:00:00', '2020-11-24T00:00:00', '2020-11-25T00:00:00',
       '2020-11-26T00:00:00', '2020-11-27T00:00:00', '2020-11-28T00:00:00'])
```

I want it to be stored as:

```
Index(['2020-11-17', '2020-11-18', '2020-11-19',
       '2020-11-20', '2020-11-21', '2020-11-22',
       '2020-11-23', '2020-11-24', '2020-11-25',
       '2020-11-26', '2020-11-27', '2020-11-28'])
```

So, basically with just the date in yyyy-mm-dd format. I was trying to use datetime but I can't seem to get it to work, possibly because this variable is an index, not an array. How do I reformat this?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the index of your dataframe using pandas [reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) method. Note that this will rename the date column to 'index', so you may want to rename it using pandas [rename()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method.

Then you can use pandas [strftime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) method to reformat your dates. After reformatting, if you still want to use the date column as the index, you can do that by changing the index attribute of the dataframe (see code below):

```
df.index = df['Date']
```

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) worked for me:

```
pd.to_datetime(dates_city)
#DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-17', '2020-11-18', '2020-11-19', '2020-11-20',
#               '2020-11-21', '2020-11-22', '2020-11-23', '2020-11-24',
#               '2020-11-25', '2020-11-26', '2020-11-27', '2020-11-28'],
#              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

If you want to keep it as `pandas.Index`, you can add the method [`pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
pd.to_datetime(dates_city).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
#Index(['2020-11-17', '2020-11-18', '2020-11-19', '2020-11-20', '2020-11-21',
#       '2020-11-22', '2020-11-23', '2020-11-24', '2020-11-25', '2020-11-26',
#       '2020-11-27', '2020-11-28'],
#      dtype='object')
```

You can find the datetime format codes [**here**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).